# If get field with multiple values

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an if statement involving a get field. However I would like it have an option of 2 different values.

This is what I currently have

```
<?php 
        if(get_field('more_links')): 
        ?>
```

I would it like go if have more_links or exp_link or both do this. I know the below wont work but just to help show what I mean.

```
<?php 
        if(get_field('more_links, exp_link')): 
        ?>
```

Comment: something like that ?
if(get_field('more_links') && get_field('exp_link')):

Comment: yes something along those lines but that didnt work. This works if both more_links and exp_link are both there, but sometimes only one is there and I still want it to be displayed

Comment: To me get_field should return the value of a field. By writing if(get_field('more_links')) you test that the value returned by get_field is 'true'.
Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default you need to call this function more than just once, if you want more than you param. You can call this like `if(get_field('exp_link') && get_field('more_links')):`, or you can create a wrapper that receives an array and call get_field foreach value on the parameter

Comment: is there a way something like this if(get_field('more_links') && get_field('experience_link') || get_field('experience_link') || get_field('more_links') ): to create all out comes? so both together or them singularly ?

Comment: It seems if(get_field('exp_link') || get_field('more_links')) would be  suitable for you.